# Использование базы данных в приложении winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server, entity-framework

Есть толстый клиент написанный на winforms. К нему подключена база данных mssql. Mdf файл лежит в корне проекта, рядом с project файлом. Коннект из visual studio смотрит на неё. Всё работало раньше, но при новом запуске на другом компьютере появилась ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос, почему visual studio пытается создать базу а не использует ту которая уже есть?

Context.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace AutoService.Models
{
    class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context()
            : base("AutoServiceConnection")
        { }

        public DbSet<Clients> Clients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Working> Working { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Spares> Spares { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: А какой вы используете инициализатор вашего контекста бд?

Comment: @tym32167 немного не понял вопроса. Что за инициализатор? Если вам нужен мой класс контекста, тогда выкладываю его код в вопрос.

Comment: попробуй добавить в конструктор
`Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Context>());
`

Comment: Проверьте права доступа к файлу.

Comment: @Pyrejkee немного не понял как это добавить в конструктор? ещё 1 строчка? Не могли бы вы показать полный пример с моим кодом

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk где можно проверить права, поподробнее пожалуйста

Comment: У тебя в класе определен конструктор, скопируй туда то,  что я скинул

Comment: @Андрей правой клавишей по файлу в проводнике "Свойства". Проверьте чтобы файл не был только на чтение и чтобы у текущего пользователя были права записи в файл.